# PHP GD: Outputted Image is the wrong size

Tags: php, gd

I'm starting back into GD library and I'm having a simple problem.  The image that is outputted is the wrong size.  It's always the same size, no matter what size I try to make it.  Here's the code:

```
$pW = 15;
$pH = 30;
$numW = 100;
$numH = $numW/2;
$sizeW = $pW*$numW;
$sizeH = $pH*$numH;

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($sizeW, $sizeH);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

This simple code is trying to make an image that is 1500px wide x 1500px high.  But when it outputs, it's always showing width and height of 527px;.

Here's the output:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" src="http://sample.com/example.php" width="527" height="527">
```

As you can see the width and height is 527.  Even when I change the height and width manually on the `imagecreatetruecolor()` it outputs always to 527.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's YOUR html setting the size. GD itself doesn't produce anything to do with html. that's not its job. If you right click the image -> view image, you'll get your 1500x1500 picture.

Comment: strange, I have zero CSS or HTML setting the size on it.  So if I were to save this image into a folder, I'd get a 1500x1500 image?

Comment: @MarcB, Thanks, I feel like a dummy